# How can I convert this line of Jquery into pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert the Jquery code below into pure working JavaScript?

```
var newPage = $(this).data("page");
```

I've attempted the following code, but when I output it to the console I get undefined.

```
var newPage = this.dataset.page;
```

Comment: Your code is correct and should work. Without seeing a working example of the problem, we can't really help

Comment: First, find out what the contextual value of 'this' is, by doing console.log(this); in your browser. 'this' is probably not the element you expect.

Comment: @PhilBlunt so when I review the console output for console.log(this) I see <li><a data-page="3" class="page-link">Year 3</a> which leads me to believe that I need to do something like this.nextSibling to get the data that I want. What are your thoughts?

Comment: this.firstChild would probably be what you want :) If useful, please vote up!

Comment: @PhilBlunt that returns <a data-page="3" class="page-link">Year 3</a> how would it be possible to return 3, the data-page value?

Comment: this.firstChild.dataset.page is probably what you need. If it helps, please vote up!

Comment: That was the solution I was looking for! Thank you so much @PhilBlunt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208859/discussion-between-phil-blunt-and-jeppy7).

Answer (score 3):

jQuery `data()` reads a *jQuery-specific* pool of data that is associated with the element.

That pool is initially populated with the values of `data-*` attributes, but then becomes independent.

If `this.dataset.page` is `undefined` then `$(this).data("page")` was probably initially **set** with jQuery and there's no reasonable way to access the data without first changing how it is set.

Comment: So when I review the console output for console.log(this) I see <li><a data-page="3" class="page-link">Year 3</a> which leads me to believe that I need to do something like this.nextSibling to get the data that I want. What are your thoughts?

Comment: The anchor is a child of the list item, not a sibling. `this.querySelector('a')`